# Site em Reactjs com Nginx não comunica com apis

Tags: node.js, react, nginx

Estou com um site em reactjs que está rodando normalmente com o Nginx, mas não consigo fazer ele se comunicar com nenhuma api, estou rodando as apis com o pm2 e consigo comunicação normal com elas através do postman.
Minhas apis são em nodejs e o meu site precisa consumir essas apis para rodar todas as funcionalidades.

Preciso que ele consigo se comunicar com essas apis que estão todas no mesmo servidor.

Tentei muitas coisas e estou aberto a sugestões, desde já fico grato.
Alterei no site para tentar localhost:3001/users e localhost/api/users, não obtive sucesso.

segue o que tem no meu arquivo dentro de sites-available do nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/react/dist;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name exemplo.com.br;

         location /api1/ {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
         }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: uma coisa que me chamou atenção é que tem um número 1 ali logo depois da palavra `api` isso é proposital?

Comment: sim, é que tenho 4 apis para esse site e estava nomeando para teste como api1, api2, api3 e api4

Comment: fiz conforme vc me passou e alterei o site para requisitar no caminho http://localhost/api1/users/authentication e não deu certo.

Comment: pois é cara, mas eu acho que agora o problema é configuração na aplicação react, não no nginx.

Comment: uam maneira simples de debuggar é acessando a api via nginx, sem usar o frontend, se ela responder, então o problema é a configuração da aplicação react.

Comment: para fazer esse teste acesse via o browser o endereço `http://localhost/api1/users/authentication` ou uma rota default que tenha uma mensagem fixa.... em meus serviços eu sempre tenho uma rota `/` (configurada no backend) que possui uma mensagem `server up and running...` para depurar nesse tipo de situação.

Comment: aí que está o problema, quando rodo a aplicação localmente tudo funciona, até mesmo utilizando docker para subir as apis e o site em nginx, tudo funciona, quando subo para a vps e utilizo docker ou pm2 o site não comunica com as apis.

Comment: consigo acessar a api normalmente sem o front-end através do navegador.

Comment: recebo esse erro no console do navegador POST http://localhost:3001/users/authentication net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: pois é cara , esse é  o problema, em sua aplicação react, você está "deixando" hardcoded o valor do endereço "localhost" isso não é um valor válido na internet. Vai ter que configurar este endereço no momento do build.

Comment: Você vai ter que trocar o valor "localhost" (no frontend) pelo ip (válido) do servidor.

Comment: o endereço que deve acessar na aplicação, de acordo com as configurações que postou, vai ser alguma coisa desse tipo: `http://<enderecodoserver>/api1/users/authentication`, repare que aqui não tem localhost, não tem porta, esse chaveamento deve ser feito via o nginx.

Comment: desculpa o incomodo aí mas vou perguntando, dessa forma não seria expor a minha api a internet, até onde acho que sei posso configurar o cors para permitir requisições apenas de determinada url, mas pensei que poderia continuar consumindo pelo localhost por estar no mesmo servidor e não precisar expor no ip da vps.

Comment: Não pode, porque o valor localhost (endereço ip: 127.0.0.1) é um número de ip privado, isso não é um valor válido para roteadores de borda da internet, vai ter que estudar um pouco de redes para entender melhor. Mas o seu endereço já está sendo exposto para acessar o frontend... qual a preocupação em relação à isso?

Comment: sempre acabo lendo em alguns lugares como medium que o recomendável é nunca expor nada, realmente preciso estudar muitas coisas ainda, vou fazer alguns testes aqui e qualquer coisa te aviso, obrigado por hora

Comment: deu certo aqui, muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: agora no caso eu preciso configurar o meu cors para receber requisições apenas do meu ip do servidor, correto? é a minha primeira vez subindo algo em um servidor.

Comment: Sim, você está correto.

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Eu corrigiria o seu sites-available para conter as seguintes três correções:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/react/dist;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _; #<-- substituir por underline

         location /api1 { #<-- Remover a barra daqui
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3001; #<-- remover a barra daqui
         }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Após fazer essas mudanças executar o comando para testar o arquivo (nginx -t) fazer o reload do arquivo `sites-available` (nginx -s reload).

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Saída esperada do comando:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

E depois fazer um reload do arquivo sites-available com o seguinte comando:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```